# Datatables footercallback no trabaja

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, callback

Mi datatable funciona muy bien, no me muestra ningun error en la consola incluso luego de que añadí footercallback como me muestra el ejemplo de la pagina oficial de datatables https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html . Sin embargo, no me muestra la suma de los totales.

De lo que me pude dar cuenta es que en el ejemplo de la página oficial están usando jquery-1.12.4.js y yo uso la versión jquery-3.1.1.js, pienso que aquí debe estar el error, pero no hay documentación sobre footercallback en la versión 3.1.1, ayudaaaa!!!!!

```js
function listar()
{
 tabla=$('#tbllistado').dataTable(
 {
  "aProcessing": true,//Activamos el procesamiento del datatables
     "aServerSide": true,//Paginación y filtrado realizados por el servidor
     dom: 'Bfrtip',//Definimos los elementos del control de tabla
     buttons: [            
              'copyHtml5',
              'excelHtml5',
              'csvHtml5',
              'pdf'
          ],
  "ajax":
    {
     url: '../ajax/ingreso.php?op=listar',
     type : "get",
     dataType : "json",      
     error: function(e){
      console.log(e.responseText); 
     }
    },
  "bDestroy": true,
  "iDisplayLength": 5,//Paginación
     "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]//Ordenar (columna,orden)
 },
 {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 3 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    }).DataTable();
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body table-responsive" id="listadoregistros">
<table id="tbllistado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
<thead>
          <th>Opciones</th>
          <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
          <th>Proveedor</th>
          <th>Total Compra</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          </thead>
<tbody>                            
</tbody>
<tfoot>
          <th colspan="3" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
          <th></th>
          </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

asd
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola saludos a mi me presenta el mismo error pero voy a investigar mas. Si consigo la solución te respondo hermano

Answer (score 0):

- Es posible que te falte un th en el footer, como se muestra en la imagen.
- También el tema de los separadores decimales, ver que es lo que aplica en tu caso

  language: {
  "decimal": ".",
  "thousands": ","
  },
- Por último fíjate si el // update footer debe incluit los
  // toLocaleString():

  // Update footer
  $(api.column(6).footer()).html(
  '' + pageTotal.toLocaleString() + ' 
   ' +
  total.toLocaleString()
  );

[image: Es posible que te falte un en el footer]